# How to specify multiple sourcefiles in automake at once

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

Is there any way around having to specify every sourcefile I create manually in my automake scripts?

I've tried several ways of specifying sourcefiles using `find -name *.cc` or the like. I've also tried finding the list in autoconf and substituting it into the Makefile.am, but automake protested that this is not allowed.

If I have to maintain the list by hand, I'm likely to keep forgetting to add newly created files to the list. I'd rather not have to do that. Is there any way to have new files selected for me automatically?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Makefile.am:

```
include srcs.am
new-src:
    # Some shell command to update srcs.am
```

Put the definition of `foo_SOURCES` in `srcs.am`. Then to update the source list, do `make new-src; make`.

This seems like a really bad idea, though. Once your project is established, you'll rarely change the file list anyway and you'll still have magic baggage hanging around.

Comment: Well then I'll just have to put the file list back in once I'm done. As a solution to my problem, this seems sensible: I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up with this:

<source>
# Use this to update the lists of sourcefiles for automake
update-sources:
 @cd src/classes && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) update-sources
 autoreconf

.PHONY: update-sources
</source>

and in src/classes/Makefile.am:
<pre>
include sources.am

# Use this to update the list of sourcefiles in src/classes
update-sources:
 @echo "libclasses_a_SOURCES = `find . -name *.cc | tr '\n' ' '`" > sources.am
 @echo "Updated sources.am"

.PHONY: update-sources
</pre>

Comment: @Romke: Use \`backticks\` around your code to get `this effect`. Use `\\\`backslashes\\\`` to get `\`this effect\``.

Comment: +1, and I really wish i could add +10 to Jack's comment that this is a really bad idea.